# Mongo Spark connector with several hosts

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, connector

I try to connect Spark to MongoDB using mongo-spark-connector_2.10-2.0.0 but it doesn't work when I have several hosts in the URI

My URI looks like that :

```
mongodb://login:password@cluster0-shard-0xxxxx:27017,cluster0-shard-0yyyyy:27017,cluster0-shard-0zzzzz:27017/database?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin
```

and I get errors like this

```
Command failed with error 8000: &apos;no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.&apos; on server cluster0-shard-0xxxxx
```

It works fine with other URIs that only have 1 host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using Atlas Free tier that requires SNI, which is not supported by the Mongo Java driver currently used by mongo-spark-connector_2.10-2.0.0.